# How can I disable Tailwind css for certain file?

Tags: next.js, tailwind-css

I want to disable tailwind for certain files, because tailwind base styles rewrites styles that came from CMS. I tried to disable preflight, but it's break all existing system. Is it possible at all?

Tailwind version - 2.2.7

My tailwind config:

````
const defaultTheme = require('tailwindcss/defaultTheme');
const colors = require('tailwindcss/colors');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'jit',
  purge: ['./src/**/*.{js,tsx}'],
  theme: {
    extend: {
      colors: {
        indigo: colors.indigo,
        green: colors.green,
        yellow: colors.yellow,
        'royal-blue': {
          100: '#F0F1FC',
          200: '#D9DCF9',
        },
        blueGray: {
          50: '#f8fafc',
          100: '#f1f5f9',
          400: '#94a3b8',
        },
      },
      fontFamily: {
        sans: ['Inter var', ...defaultTheme.fontFamily.sans],
      },
      maxWidth: {
        '8xl': '90rem',
      },
    },
  },
  variants: {},
  plugins: [
    function ({ addComponents }) {
      addComponents({
        '.container': {
          '@screen lg': {
            maxWidth: '1024px',
          },
          '@screen xl': {
            maxWidth: '1140px',
          },
        },
      });
    },
  ],
};```
````

Comment: Maybe you can be more specific in the `purge`-field? Now it's just all the js and tsx files? Please provide a folder structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to disable preflight for some CMS content then you can try to add `all: revert;` property to the needed element (and its children), that will reset most of the styles to their original values.

[Read more on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/revert)

```css
your-element-selector * {
  all: revert;
}
```